# Ubuntu 20.10 wifi disconnects 1min after boot

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi, 20.10

I just installed Ubuntu 20.10. The wifi-module disconnects 1min after every start. No wifi settings are available, it seems, that the wifi module disconnects. Just a reboot fixes the wifi but after the restart, wifi disconnets again.

Using a Asus Zenbook Pro 14 UX480, all drivers are up to date.

Adapter: Cannon Point-LP CNVi
Wifi driver: iwlwifi

Wifi working:
sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network                 
   Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
   Produkt: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
   Hersteller: Intel Corporation
   Physische ID: 14.3
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:14.3
   Logischer Name: wlo1
   Version: 30
   Seriennummer: d8:f2:ca:c3:fd:bb
   Breite: 64 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-25-generic firmware=46.8902351f.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.178.79 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   Ressourcen: irq:16 memory:b431c000-b431ffff
```

Wifi not working:
sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network UNGEFORDERT     
   Beschreibung: Network controller
   Produkt: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
   Hersteller: Intel Corporation
   Physische ID: 14.3
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:14.3
   Version: 30
   Breite: 64 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   Konfiguration: latency=0
   Ressourcen: memory:b431c000-b431ffff
```

Comment: When it doesn't work, what happens if you `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your replies. I'm just fed up with the ASUS Laptop. Switched to a Tuxedo computer with fully supported hardware. Greetings!

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal paste this command `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` press enter and then this `sudo service network-manager restart` and press enter . Hope this helps.

Comment: -1 for such a reckless use of a powertool *again*.  This could easily cause unintended changes on other systems now or in the future.  Why not '/^wifi.powersave/s/3/2/', if that's what you meant!

Comment: What's reckless in this ? Do you know its meaning and what it does ? @MartinThornton

Comment: Go to administrator root in files/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/ and open ```default-wifi-powersave-on.conf``` there is a line ```wifi.powersave = 3``` then changing it to ```wifi.powersave = 2``` is harmful? @MartinThornton

Comment: No.  But it does *more* than that!  Such as changing `something.else = 434` to `something.else = 424` if that exists on *someone else's* computer!

Comment: Ok, I understood  But that worked for me :) @MartinThornton

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tryed your solution but it didn't work. The terminal response: Failed to restart network-manager.service: Unit network-manager.service not found.

Comment: wifi.powersave = 2  in defaut-wifi-powersave.on.conf and still the same problems